# transcluded directive for a dialog needs to have it's own scope for edit actions

Tags: dialog, scope, angularjs

I have created a rather generic dialog directive for multiple uses... however when i use it to edit data .. it's still two-way bound to the scope on the original calling controller.

It's likely simple, but i'm having trouble. i need to clone the scope during the dialog, and then before the okCallback i need to copy the scope back... so a user can actually cancel.

```
<div mydialog 
    open="{{isEditDialogOpen}}"
    modal="true"
    ok-button="Yes"
    ok-callback="saveEdits"
    cancel-button="No"
    cancel-callback="dismissEditDialog"
    title="Edit Category">
        <input ng-model="categoryToEdit.name" label-text="Category Name"></input>  
</div>
```

The issue becomes evident in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenkirby/HT6X7/

edit a category, and then start typing in the box.

Any thoughts?  I'd like to keep the transclusion usage aspect of the directive.

Is there a more "angular" way of approaching/solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i concluded with the following fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenkirby/FYCXk/

I turned **transclusion off** to make use of the isolate scope.  I then do an **angular.copy** on a parametrized model value (*if it exists*).. but i grab it from

```
scope.$parent["nameOfObjectOnParent"]
```

Copying it allows me have a cancel state in my dialog for edits. An additional bonus to this isolate copy of the model being edited is that it gives me something to **$watch** on with a **validationCallback**.

I will be able to optionally put a full form on the dialog with bindings, and pass an object to it with some validation rules.

Answer (score 1):

When the edit form is displayed, copy the current data values into a variable/property:

```
$scope.showEditDialog = function(category, index){
    $scope.index = index;
    $scope.origData = angular.copy(category);
```

If the user hits cancel/No, restore it:

```
$scope.dismissEditDialog = function(){
    $scope.categories[$scope.index] = $scope.origData;
```

HTML change:

```
<a ng-click="showEditDialog(category, $index)">Edit</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/bkzyU/)

Comment: so then the trancluded html needs to be bound to the origData ?

Comment: i think this is a step in the right direction. i still would prefer the reverse.  when the save button is clicked make the change.. not the vice versa.   i'll keep fiddling.  i appreciate the help.

Comment: this is essentially what you are suggesting. http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenkirby/WUVVJ/1/     what i guess i was hoping for was a way to build this into the directive and parametrize it. soo the calling controller wouldn't have to.

Comment: another reason why i was hoping for a seperate directive scope was for validation purposes.  i could watch on the values and apply logic to disable and gray out the confirm/decline buttons... if invalid.